# Why cant the function gf be formed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the functions $f$ and $g$:

$f(x) = \frac{8}{x-2}+2$ for $x > 2$

$g(x) = \frac{8}{x-2}+2$ for $2 < x < 4$

Explain why the function gf cannot be formed.

---

I attempted solving this by trying to derive $gf$ as follows:

$gf(x) = g(f(x))$

$gf(x) = \frac{8}{(\frac{8}{x-2}+2)-2}+2$

Simplifying, I got $gf(x) = x$. This appears perfectly fine to me. What have I missed?

Comment: $g(x)$ is only defined for $x<4$.

Comment: Try $x = 3$, then $f(x) = 10$ and $g(f(x)) = g(10)$ which is not defined. You should always pay attention to the domains of definition.

Comment: 2 < f(x) < 4 is the domain of g(f(x)) and hence 4 < x <  6

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a matter of convention. The composition $\;g(f(x))\;$ makes sense if $\;x\;$ is in the domain of $\;f\;$ **and** if $\;f(x)\;$ is in the domain of $\;g.\;$ Thus the domain of the composition will be, in general, a subset of the domain of $\;f.\;$ In the particular case you asked about, if $\;x>6\;$ then $\;y:=f(x)\;$ will satisfy $\;2<y<4\;$ and so $\;g(f(x)) = x\;$ but it is only defined if $\;x>6.\;$